# Query to online game server to get its status Delphi - Indy 10

Tags: delphi, minecraft, indy10, bukkit

I am trying to find out how to establish a connection between a
Delphi application and an online game server in this case Minecraft running with Bukkit.

The search was not successful, but I have a vague idea
using maybe Indy 10 components? like TIdTCPClient
but I think it needs a handler, I dont know which one.

Then I want to ask.

How to query an online server?

With PHP:
https://github.com/FunnyItsElmo/PHP-Minecraft-Server-Status-Query

Any idea coming up?

Sorry for my English
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MJN said, once you `Connect()` to the server, you use the `TIdIOHandler.IOHandler` property to read/write data as needed, eg:

```
var
  data: TIdBytes;

Client.Host := AHost;
Client.Port := APort;
Client.ConnectTimeout := 3000;
Client.ReadTimeout := 3000;

Client.Connect;
try
  Client.IOHandler.Write(Byte($FE));
  Client.IOHandler.Write(Byte($01));
  Client.IOHandler.ReadBytes(data, 2048);
finally
  Client.Disconnect;
end;

// parse data as needed...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no additional "Handler" required for TIdTCPClient to connect with the server.

A TIdTCPClient instance contains an IOHandler (exposed as a property).

Use this IOHandler to read bytes from the server.

The [PHP source code](https://github.com/FunnyItsElmo/PHP-Minecraft-Server-Status-Query/blob/master/MinecraftServerStatus/status.class.php) for Minecraft server status queries seems to be quite short and easy to understand, it will be no problem to port it to Delphi.

Comment: To elaborate - `TIdTCPClient.Connect()` creates and assigns its own `TIdIOHandler` object internally if you do not provide one beforehand (such as an SSL IOHandler).